# Whenever I switch from another window to Google Chrome, my mouse stutters for a few seconds

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

Whenever I switch from another window to Google Chrome, my mouse stutters/lags for a few seconds. I have tried restarting my computer and installing updates for windows and graphics card, but this didn't help. Not sure what is causing this, but it is really slowing down my productivity. Please help